# Aside from the damage-over-time effect and spy checking, does being set on fire have other effects on robots?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

Aside from the damage-over-time effect and spy checking, does [being set on fire](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fire) have other effects on [robots](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Robots)?

e.g. Are Sniper robots unable to fire their primary weapon if they are set on fire? What about other effects?

Comment: I can guess it messes up the aim-bots/snipers aim a bit but it could also force medics to pop ubers maybe, if you wanted that.

Comment: @Dycker I'm looking for an answer like that. Could you confirm if it messes the aim of the robots?

Comment: I have no proof sadly, just that little feeling inside knowing I made their day worse. That and I feel their aim is worse.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - the fire does skew the aim of the robots. I tested it out and it does do the same damage and will cause the bots to sometimes to go a different path.

Answer (score -1):

I am 99% sure that fire has the same effects on robots in MvM that is does on players in normal game modes.
As Dycker mentioned, it messes up the aim of bots/snipers.

edit: i didnt find any document on the internet, that writes it would be different in the other (normal) game mode. Now i am 100% sure.

Comment: As the OP commented, he wants an answer that can confirm, not "I'm 99% sure".